# Finish plot in same code chunk and start new when using mfcol

Tags: r, knitr

Is there a way in `knitr` to finish off a plot within a code chunk and start a new one when you have used `par`'s `mfcol` argument to have multiple figures in the same plot. My code is roughly like

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Not me"
date: "October 14, 2017"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
set.seed(73856421)

# Plot random number of graphs
par(mfcol = c(2, 2))
for(i in 1:sample.int(6, 1)) # not in control of the number of plots here
  plot(rnorm(100))

# <-- want plot here

# ...
# some other code
# ....

# plot new results
plot(1, type = "n", xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1))
text(.5, .5, "should be")
plot(1, type = "n", xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1))
text(.5, .5, "together")
plot(1, type = "n", xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1))
text(.5, .5, "in new")
plot(1, type = "n", xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1))
text(.5, .5, "4x4 plot")
```
````

The issue is that the first 4x4 plot does not show at `# <-- want plot here` and it has two of the next figures in it. My best solution so far is to keep track of the number of figures and use `plot.new` or `frame` to make empty figures for the "missing" figures. This is a tedious though in my current setup which is more complicated than above.